# Why isn't this a counter example to "Linear Fractional Transformations are Automorphisms of $\mathbb C \cup \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

$\frac{Z-1}{2Z-4}$ is a linear fractional transformation, but it cannot take on the value $\frac{1}{2}$ -- so how can it be an Automorphisms of the Extended complex plane?

Comment: Rewriting this, we get $\frac{1-1/z}{2-4/z}$. So at "$z=\infty$", this would be $\frac{1-0}{2-0}=1/2$. Remember that you are talking about the EXTENDED complex plane, and so also need to consider the image of the point at infinity.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to check that point.

Comment: @TomCooney, you should write that comment as an answer.

Comment: Linear fractional = Moebius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll repeat my comment as an answer and so remove this from the list of unanswered questions.

First of all, an informal answer. Here we are talking about automorphisms of the $\textit{extended}$ complex plane so we also have to consider the image of the point at infinity. If we divided above and below by $z$, we could rewrite this linear fractional transformation as
$$
\frac{1 -\frac{1}{z}}{2-\frac{4}{z}}.
$$
If we pretend for a moment that $\infty$ is a number, we would expect it to be mapped to 
$$
\frac{1 -0}{2-0}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
So the answer is that the point at infinity is mapped to $\frac{1}{2}$.

More carefully, if we look at the [definition of a linear fractional transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearFractionalTransformation.html), we see that a linear fractional transformation treats the point at infinity slightly differently from the rest. This definition agrees with the answer obtained by pretending $\infty$ is a number. If 
$$
f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}, \quad ad-bc \neq 0,
$$
we define $f(\infty)=\frac{a}{c}$ and $f(\frac{-d}{c})=\infty$. So for the linear fractional transformation in the question, $f(\infty)=\frac{1}{2}$ by definition.